# Delete rows Excel VBA within selected Cels

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I would like to delete entire rows when cells are blank in column B, but I want to skip some of the cells. I managed to work out a code for the first part, but I want to skip two rows and then let the code delete the next part.

First part is B4:B13 and the next is B16:B27[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It uses a discontinuous range (as you need) and delete all the rows at the end of the code, at once. Being very fast, even on big ranges:

```
Sub testDeleteRowsDiscontinuousRange()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, C As Range, rngDel As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your necessary sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = sh.Range("B4:B13,B16:B27")
  
  For Each C In rng.cells
    If C.Value = "" Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
           Set rngDel = C
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, C)
        End If
    End If
  Next C
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but it still deletes the middle two cells... (B14 and B15)

Comment: @Jerry Fung: Ups... Yes, iteration between the cells(i) includes the one not being part of the range. I will adapt the code in one, two minutes... **Adapted**. Now, it uses strictly the discontinuous range cells... Test the updated code, please.

Comment: @Jerry Fung: Glad i could help! Sorry for the previous variant. I did not realize that the iteration may exceed the discontinuous range. I did not test the code. It looked so simple... :)